# Not found route in Laravel 7

Tags: php, routes, laravel-7

Making a website on Laravel 7.28.
Added a route to '*routes/web.php*':

```
...
    Route::get('/lk', 'LK\IndexController@index')->name('lk');
...

+--------+----------+------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                    | Name                        | Action                                                                 | Middleware |
+--------+----------+------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                      | generated::0jR7DUWQf5HIAEoc | Illuminate\Routing\ViewController                                      | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | home                   | home                        | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              | web        |
|        |          |                        |                             |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD | lk                     | lk                          | App\Http\Controllers\LK\IndexController@index                          | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | login                  | login                       | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web        |
```

The controller is created in '*app\Http\Controllers\LK\IndexController.php*'.
It has a method:

```
    public function index()
    {
        return view('lk.index');
    }
```

Created promoter file '*resources\views\lk\index.blade.php*'.
When I'm trying to follow the route *`http://127.0.0.1:8000/lk`*. I get an error:

> The requested resource /lk was not found on this server.

If I change the 'lk' routes to the 'account', for example, then at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/account' I get the page correctly.

And it's not entirely clear why 404 error doesn't appear in Laravel view?
Please help with this issue.Thank.

Comment: Please verify once whether you've duplicate url which is overriding this route and causing this error.

Comment: Have you update route cache?

Comment: @Alberto Valerio Yes of course.

Comment: @Jitendra Yadav.Route::view('/', 'welcome');

Route::get('/lk', 'LK\IndexController@index')->name('lk');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');  I don't see duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Issue***:This error occurs when you create a folder/directory in the `public` folder with the same name as route slug(`lk` here).

***Why public folder creating this issue***: Any object inside public folder can be accessed via `url`(which is also a route).

If you have a directory(folder) with the same name as route mentioned, it will create `404` because `/directory` can't be accessed due to blocking of directory traversal for security reasons but if you use `/directory/<a_file_or_image>` it will show you the requested object.

When you have a route with same name as directory inside public folder, it is being override by public path. When you change to another route name, it works fine.

***Solution***:
Either change public folder name or change route slug.

Comment: I changed the 'lk' folder to 'personal' in views. But route '/lk' still gives a 404 error exactly to apache.
When I changed route to '/personal' (for example) everything worked. It is unclear why '/lk' did not work.